# Express res.json() to Angular $http.get() format problems

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes

How do I get my data from `res.json()` [Server] response object in `$http.get()` [Controller]?

I have a feeling it's something to do with `content-type` as I do not want to manually type `$scope.message = data.data.message;`

I am playing around with the MEAN stack and trying to display data from Express into Angular with `ng-bind`.

`Server.js` uses `.get()` on `/api` route to respond with a simple object `res.json({ message : 'Hello World' })` as seen below:

```
...
// Server frontend view
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Configure bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json

// Specify backend route
router.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.json({message : 'Hello World'});
});
...
```

---

Angular controller uses a simple `$http.get('/api/)` to retrieve that data as seen below:

```
...
$http.get('/api')
  .then(data => {
    $scope.message = data;
      console.log('Data: ' + data);
   }, err => {
     console.log('Error: ' + err);
   });
...
```

---

When I test `localhost:port/api`, I see `{message:'Hello World'}`,
when I use `localhost:port` which is my Angular view, I see this data:

> {"data":{"message":"Hello
>   World"},"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` parameter is in fact [response object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns), and response body is available as `data` property. It should be:

```
$http.get('/api')
  .then(({ data }) => {
    $scope.message = data;
      console.log('Data: ' + data);
   }, err => {
     console.log('Error: ' + err);
   });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Is this a standard way of doing things?